# Exposing localhost ports in several local services

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm currently attempting to use Docker to make our local dev experience involving two services easier, but I'm struggling to use host and container ports in the right way. Here's the situation:

- One repo containing a Rails API, running on 127.0.0.1:3000 (lets call this `backend`)
- One repo containing an isomorphic React/Redux frontend app, running on 127.0.0.1:8080 (lets call this `frontend`)
- Both have their own Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files as they are in separate repos, and both start with `docker-compose up` fine.
- Currently not using Docker at all for CI or deployment, planning to in the future.

The issue I'm having is that in local development the `frontend` app is looking for the API backend on 127.0.0.1:3000 from within the `frontend` container, which isn't there - it's only available to the host and the `backend` container actually running the Rails app.

Is it possible to forward the `backend` container's 3000 port to the frontend container? Or at the very least the host's 3000 port as I can see the Rails app on localhost on my computer. I've tried `127.0.0.1:3000:3000` within the `frontend` docker-compose but I can't do that while running the Rails app as the port is in use and fails to connect. I'm thinking maybe I've misunderstood the point or am missing something obvious?

Files:

`frontend` Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.7.0
RUN npm install --global --silent webpack yarn
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY  package.json /app/package.json
COPY yarn.lock /app/yarn.lock
RUN yarn install
COPY . /app
```

`frontend` docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: yarn start:dev
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '127.0.0.1:3000:3000' # rails backend exposed to localhost within container
```

`backend` Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.4.2
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /app
```

`backend` docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this using external links in the frontend app to link to the default network of the backend app like so:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: yarn start:dev
    environment:
      - API_HOST=http://backend_web_1:3000
    external_links:
      - backend_default
    networks:
      - default
      - backend_default
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - .:/app

networks:
  backend_default: # share with backend app
    external: true
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to unite the containers in one **network**. Do it in your docker-compose.yml files.

Check this [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks) to learn about networks in docker.

`frontend` docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  gui:
    build: .
    command: yarn start:dev
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '127.0.0.1:3000:3000' 
    networks:
       - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```

`backend` docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  back:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - postgres


       networks:
           - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```

Docker has its own DNS resolution, so after you do this you will be able to connect to your backend by setting the address to: `http://back:3000`

Comment: In case you need to run these docker-compose files together, it's done this way `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d`

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried the above but it ended up creating two networks `frontend_webnet` and `backend_webnet`, do I have to use some sort of aliasing? Or perhaps external links?

Comment: Did you try running starting them both by one command as I wrote above?

Comment: It's strange...hm, where do those prefixes come from..? Did you mention it anywhere?

Comment: The name of the project i think - I don't really want to run them together as they are in different repos.

I manage to sort using `external_links` and the default network name, thanks for the help